# Compressing mysql data folder to save in a docker image

Tags: mysql, docker

For internal dev productivity usecase, we are building docker images for every build by installing our application which includes glassfish application server and mysql database and keeping the application server and database in stopped state before saving the docker image. On container startup, database and application server are started in that order.

In order to reduce the docker image size, i am planning to compress the mysql data folder and keep the .tar.gz file only in the docker image. Container startup will uncompress the data folder before starting the database. Are there any issues with this approach in case anyone has gone down this path?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is a fairly good approach to go with.

1. You can compress the data into tar either by going inside the container and running tar command. Then you can just edit rc.local where you can put a restart script which will run when the container boots up and untars the tar file in the appropriate directory and then Later you can make an image out of this.

OR

2. Create image of your container. Then use Dockerfile to do what I explained above. put this image over DockerHub and pull it on a different machine, run it and it should run what you want. You can also make use of CMD to start database.

OR

3. Simply just tar the data, ship the Docker Image. Pull it on which ever server you want to, keep and untar command handy. Run the container, get into it, untar the file and then start your database server.